# Autocompletion for types that can be dynamically anything - not working

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I have auto-completion for `Python` with the `Python` and `IntelliSense` extensions installed.

I installed the package `matplotlib` and completion works for this

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt. #figure() shows in completion menu
```

but when I try this

```
fig = plt.figure()

fig. # no completion menu. Specifically looking for suptitle()
```

[EDIT] Seems like this is actually related to Python being dynamic. For example, hinting at the type gets it to complete

```
fig = plt.figure()
assert isinstance(fig, figure.Figure)
fig. # now completes perfectly
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, auto completion highly depend on type information.

The reason of IDE does not tell you what method or data field it have is because:

1. If the type can not derive in compile time(or "before execution"), IDE does not know what it is.
2. Actually IDE can do auto completion if it scan all possible path but it is does not make sense, performance will be very bad.

After [python 3.5](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/), we can specify method return type. If matplotlib add type hint, IDE can support auto completion.

By the way, the reason of IDE needs to indexing file when project first time load in is because it need to parse source code and get type information.